# Incorrect Number of Dimensions on Train and Test Dataset

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am running a machine learning algorithms in a loop. Everything is working perfectly but at where I have to split and train the data, I get error saying incorrect number of dimensions.

1. I have a data from UCI; heart disease
2. Now I am applying MCAR mechanism and imputations methods
3. Machine learning algorithms

The data can be downloaded using this link (https://www.kaggle.com/code/mchtklb/kalebasi-heart-disease-ml-modeling/data?select=heart.csv)

This is the code from where the loop starts

```
p  <- c(0.01,0.02) #generating prob of missing data
ip = 2 #number of imputations

#MICE BINS
hd_mcar  <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
mice_mcar <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
app1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
min1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
sm1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
final_clean_hd_mcar <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
mice.mcar <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))


for(i in 1:length(p)){
  hd_mcar[[i]] <- delete_MCAR(heart.ds, p[i])

  #Applying Imputation
          
  ###1. Method(MICE)
  mice_mcar[[i]] <- mice(hd_mcar[[i]], m=ip, method = c("pmm","logreg","polyreg","pmm","pmm","logreg",
                                            "polyreg","pmm","logreg","pmm","polyreg","pmm",
                                            "polyreg","logreg"), maxit = 20)

  #Diagnostic check
  summary(heart.ds$age)
  mice_mcar[[i]]$imp$age


  #Finding the means of the impuatations
  app1[[i]] <- apply(mice_mcar[[i]]$imp$age, MARGIN = 2, FUN = mean)
  min1[[i]] <- abs(app1[[i]]-mean(heart.ds$age))
  
  #Selecting the minimum index
  sm1[[i]] <- which(min1[[i]]==min(min1[[i]]))
  
  #Selecting final imputation
  final_clean_hd_mcar[[i]] =mice::complete(mice_mcar[[i]],sm1[[i]])
  mice.mcar[[i]] <- final_clean_hd_mcar[[i]]


  #MLA BINS
  control <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  results <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  vimp <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))

  #Feature Selection Using Recursive Feature Elimination
  control[[i]] <- rfeControl(functions=rfFuncs, method="cv", number=10)
  # run the RFE algorithm
  results[[i]] <- rfe(mice.mcar[[i]][,1:13], mice.mcar[[i]][,14], sizes=c(1:13), rfeControl=control[[i]], metric = "Accuracy")

  # list the chosen features
  predictors(results[[i]])


  #BINS
  n.heart.ds <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  tr.dat <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  TrainSet <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  ValidSet <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))
  fitControl <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(p))

  #Re-selection from the Feature Selection
  n.heart.ds[[i]] <- mice.mcar[[i]][,-c(2,6,7,8,9,11)]

  #Data Splitting
  set.seed(1237)
  tr.dat[[i]] <- sample(nrow(n.heart.ds[[i]]), .7*nrow(n.heart.ds[[i]]), replace = FALSE)

  TrainSet[[i]] <- n.heart.ds[tr.dat[[i]],]
  ValidSet[[i]] <- n.heart.ds[-tr.dat[[i]],]
}
```

Now at the TrainSet, I get an error:

```
Error in n.heart.ds[tr.dat[[i]], ] : incorrect number of dimensions
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Please how do I solve the error on the Training and Validation dataset? I mean the dimension errors is printing

Comment: If you provide a reproducible example it will help get answers. For example, at the moment I can't run your loop because I don't have `heart.ds`

Comment: @rw2 Please I have added a link for where the data can be found